# Using es6 transpiled classes in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, gulp, browserify, babeljs

So I have my example classes in my file `ContrivedExampleA.es6`

```
export class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
    }

    get name() {
        return this._name;
    }

    get age() {
        return this._age;
    }
}

export class Greeter {
    constructor(person) {
        this._person = person;
    }

    greet() {
        return `Hello ${this._person.name}, I believe you are ${this._person.age} years old!`;
    }
}
```

which I compile (successfully), using the following Gulp task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('build', function () {
    return browserify({entries: './src/ContrivedExampleA.es6', extensions: ['.es6'], debug: true})
        .transform(babelify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('example.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

So I want to use this code in regular Nodejs land, so I do the following:

```
"use strict";

var Person = require('./example').Person;
var Greeter = require('./example').Greeter;

var person = new Person("Test Person", 25);
var greeter = new Greeter(person);
console.log(greeter.greet());
```

However, both `Person` and `Greeter` are undefined. I've even tried including `transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` in my `.babelrc` file which hasn't helped anything.

What am I doing wrong? and how can I get these transpiled ES6 classes imported into a regular Nodejs file?

***EDIT***

I also have a `.babelrc` file which looks like:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore my previous answer, I was focusing on the wrong thing.

If you want to get the regular ES6 classes imported into a Nodejs file, you could skip the browserify and babelify steps all together, and just use the `gulp-babel` plugin directly. I would recommend using `gulp-rename` too.

Your `ContrivedExampleA.es6` file would stay the same, but your `gulpfile.js` would become:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('build', function () {
    return gulp.src('./src/ContrivedExampleA.es6')
        .pipe(babel({presets: ["es2015"], plugins: ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]}))
        .pipe(rename('example.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

Note: since you have a `.babelrc` you could probably skip passing the options to babel.

Then in your node file, you could simply do

```
"use strict";

var Person = require('./example').Person;
var Greeter = require('./example').Greeter;

var person = new Person("Test Person", 25);
var greeter = new Greeter(person);
console.log(greeter.greet());
```

Comment: I do already have that in my .babelrc file, but I will try that!

Comment: @DamonSwayn I had some more time, see my fixed answer above.